# focus() input element with jQuery, but the cursor doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, focus, text-cursor

I want to focus an input element when a div is clicked.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="placeholder_input">
    <input type="text" id="username" maxlength="100" />
    <div class="placeholder_container">
        <div class="placeholder">username</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my script is:

```
$("#username").focus(function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
});

$(".placeholder_input").mousedown(function() {              
    $(this).children(":first").focus();
});
```

When I click into the textbox, the placeholder text disappears correctly, but the blinking cursor doesn't show in the textbox. (and I can't type any text into the textbox)

Inside of the `mousedown` event handler, the `$(this).children(":first")` expression selects the correct input element, so I have no idea why the `focus()` call doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't work with the `mousedown` method; it does, though, work with the [`mouseup()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpnNY/1/) and [`click()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpnNY/) methods:

```
$(".placeholder_input").mouseup(function() {              
    $(this).children(":first").focus();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpnNY/1/).

And:

```
$(".placeholder_input").click(function() {              
    $(this).children(":first").focus();
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wpnNY/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`mouseup()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/).

Answer (score 6):

if you insist on using `mousedown`, delay the focus till the next tick

```
$(".placeholder_input").mousedown(function() {              
      var $el =  $(this).children(":first");
      setTimeout(function() {
          $el.focus();
      }, 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpnNY/46/

Answer (score 0):

`mousdown` will not work, use `click`.

```
$(".placeholder_input").click(function() {              
    $(this).children(":first").focus();
});​
```